# How to instruct sed to substitute only once while using multiple substitute expressions?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have multiple substitution rules but want to use only the first applicable rule. `sed`, by default, continues processing the output with the remaining rules. How do I break after the first substitution? Is it possible using just `sed`? I could not find an option in the manual.

*Actual output*

```bsh
$ sed "s/something/else/; s/one/two/; s/two/three/;" <<<"one"

three
```

*Desired operation*

```bsh
$ sed "s/something/else/; s/one/two/; s/two/three/;" <<<"one"

two
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `t` command after each `s` command to branch to the end of the script if a substitution was made:

```
sed -e 's/something/else/;t' \
    -e 's/one/two/;t' \
    -e 's/two/three/;t' <<<"one"
```

Here, the `t` command after the last substitution is not needed, but if you generate this code automatically, there is no problem letting it suffix each `s`, even the last.

Comment: Suggested revision:  `s/branch to the end/start the next cycle/` since there's no label at the end to branch to.

Comment: @agc No. I'm using that wording because that is what the POSIX specification as well as all `sed` manuals says happens when the `t` command is used without a label. The _effect_ will obviously be to start the next cycle, but not before _implicitly printing the pattern space at the end of the script_.

Comment: FWIW, *GNU* `sed`'s `info` page section 3.6 says about `t`:  *"The LABEL may be omitted, in which case the next cycle is started."*  (While a POSIX spec is authoritative for implementing a complaint `sed`, it's not really intended as an end-user reference.)

Comment: @agc The GNU info documentation is misleading as it does not immediately start the next cycle. It branches to the end of the script, _like every other piece of documentation says_. See e.g. the `man` manuals for `sed` on Linux, any BSD, Solaris and AIX.

Comment: @agc This is significant, because the POSIX specification says "If no commands
       explicitly started a new cycle, then at the end of the script the
       pattern space shall be copied to standard output (except when `-n` is
       specified) [...]".  This means that if the `t` command immediately started the next cycle, no default output would happen.

Comment: Re *"This means that..."*: I doubt most users would suppose that -- for users STDOUT printing is implied by *"start the next cycle"*.  On the other hand *"the end of the script"* might well confuse users, because if nothing happens that they don't already expect, then *why even mention it*?  To mention something a reader hadn't considered significant can connote an implication of some new possibility... example, the old joke about a ship's log entry *"The Captain was not drunk last night."*  Which would be true if the Captain were a lifelong teetotaler, but connotes that sobriety is unusual.

Comment: Anyway we don't disagree about any technical point!  Only on how best to present it.

Answer (score 2):

sed with branch 't' in other command is the perfect answer.

This is just a suggestion , in case if you want to do multiple stuff inside if its replaced , you can use **awk**:

```
awk ' { if (gsub("something","else",$0) || gsub("one","two",$0) || gsub("two","three",$0) ){ print $0;exit}; }' <<<"one"
```

Comment: More idiomatic: `awk 'gsub("something","else",$0) || gsub("one","two",$0) || gsub("two","three",$0) {print; exit}'`

Comment: Yeah correct , even for all gsub also we don't require $0 i think...

Answer (score 1):

These are evaluated in order, so if there is no circle and you can easily do so, you can just use

```
s/two/three/; s/one/two/; s/something/else/
```

If there is a circle, or the list is generated from other data, you can use a marker, e.g.

```
s/@/@@/g
s/one/t@wo/
s/two/t@hree/
s/something/e@lse/
s/@\(.\)/\1/g
```

Comment: Markers would work if a `sed` lacks a working `t`, but markers are less efficient -- *e.g.* with `t` a successful first search then skips the next two searches, but markers make `sed` search for every target every time.